# How to setup Admob Android AIR with Pozirk method

Tags: android, actionscript-3, admob, flashdevelop, flash-cs6

Hey everyone so It's been about 2 days now and still have no luck trying to setup admob with my application I don't understand what im doing wrong. Or really how to do it. Here is the link to the website with the instruction that i followed to the T! But still no success Ughh.

Here is what I have so far in my startGameScreen Class:

```
import com.pozirk.ads.admob.AdMob;
import com.pozirk.ads.admob.AdParams;
import com.pozirk.ads.admob.AdEvent;




/**
 * ...
 * @author Fitchett Development 
 */
public class startGameScreen extends MovieClip 
{
    public var mcStart:MovieClip;
    public var btnMainMenu:MovieClip;
    public var btnCredits:MovieClip
    private var sndmainSong:Sound;
    private var mainChannel:SoundChannel;

    protected var _admob:AdMob = new AdMob();



    public function startGameScreen() 
    {

        _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INIT_OK, onEvent);
        _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INIT_FAIL, onEvent);
        _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.AD_SHOW_OK, onEvent);
        _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.AD_SHOW_FAIL, onEvent);
        _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.PRESENT_SCREEN, onEvent);
        _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.DISMISS_SCREEN, onEvent);
        _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.LEAVE_APPLICATION, onEvent);
        _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INTERSTITIAL_CACHE_OK, onEvent);
        _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INTERSTITIAL_CACHE_OK, onEvent);
        _admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INTERSTITIAL_CLOSED, onEvent);





        mcStart.buttonMode = true;

        mcStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startOnClick);



        //To completely end game when back button pushed on android
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown, false, 0, true);
        mainChannel;
        sndmainSong = new DST10Class();
        mainChannel = sndmainSong.play();



    }



 protected function onEvent(ae:AdEvent):void
 {
_admob.init("pub-3779806175107707");
_admob.show(AdParams.SIZE_SMART, AdParams.HALIGN_CENTER,  AdParams.VALIGN_TOP);
    trace(ae.type+" "+ae._data);
  }
```

Please how do i Do this! I just want ads in this game. ANny help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the show function as soon as

```
_admob.addEventListener(AdEvent.INIT_OK, onEvent);
```

is triggered. But the problem is that event is never called as you are never initializing the ads system. So the solution is to call `init()` in `startGameScreen()` and `show()` in `onEvent()` after `(AdEvent.INIT_OK)`

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using the new admob (after upgrade). So, you have to use the updated ane of admob as well. Pozirk already has published the new version.